# Interactive mirror (Ctrl + M) doesn't mirror object

Tags: mirror

I'm trying to simply mirror an object (maybe for the first time)

So I want to use the mirror command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> for it.

When  use it, blender asks to select the axis I want to use for the mirror operation, then I type `X`, `Y` or `Z`, the axis is selected, I press enter or click anywhere, and nothing happens, the object just sits there the same way.

[image: after I type <code>ctr+m</code>Blender asks to select a mirror axis]

[image: one of the axis is slected, then I press enter but nothing happens]

What could it be the problem? I can't find info about this problem.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you upload some screenshots or a .blend?

Comment: OK, i edited the question, now it has screenshots. should i mention i'm using mac?

Comment: I think it's working, but as your object is symmetrical on all three axes it will look the same. Try it on a Suzanne.

Comment: But how does it need to be done to face in a different way?...and what's a Suzanne?

Comment: Suzanne is the name of the monkey head (Add > Mesh > Monkey) ;). I'm not sure mirror does what you think it does (and I'm not sure what you want it to do)..

Comment: I think part of the problem is that the question (or answer) is so extrmely simple that is misleading.
It seems like Blender mirrors in the local axis by default and since the object was completly symmetrical i couldn't see any change. So just repeating the axis after the command did the trick. thanks!

Comment: @invicente It actually mirrors in global by default.

Comment: ...well then i don't get it. how did i change this ?

Comment: @invicente It's nothing to worry about, most of the time you want to mirror in the global by default, this is where it mirrors the first axis you press.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using *Interactive mirror* as with the mirror modifier, you need to mirror about a *point* else pertaining to the former, the object will just mirror/flip in place and if the object is symmetrical you won't see any changes. This point can be the object origin, another object or the 3d cursor depending on which mode you are using.

You can either change the object's origin or simply switch the pivot point to use the *3d cursor* and then mirror.

It is also worth noting that mirroring basically just scales the object on the desired axis by -1 (so without applied rotation you might not get expected results). So as a cheap and quick alternative to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, you could just select the object and use <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> `-1`.

### Mirroring in place or right on the object origin or 3d cursor.

[image]

### Mirroring about a point

[image]

[image]

What I did in the last example was to first translate the object over a bit on the *X* axis and then change the pivot mode to the *3d cursor* as the mirror tool needs a point to work around. I then invoked interactive mirror and selected the axis I wanted to mirror on which in the example is the *X axis*. In the first one, I simply mirrored a single object and it flipped it to the opposite side, in the second, I duplicated the object and then mirrored so I had identical copies.

Comment: Also as a side note, maybe add that mirroring actually just scales by -1 (so without applied rotation you might not get expected results)?

Comment: @gandalf3 another side note: Better use it in **Object** mode. Scale by negative value will flip normals when in **Edit** mode.

Answer (score -1):

It only works in edit mode:
As per the [Blender documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/mirror.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/45876)

Comment: @batFINGER: Thank you very much for guide line, I will do in future posts

Comment: Nothing in the page linked corresponds to that. The first sentense states otherwise (and it's actually how it works), pointing out Object or Mesh selection (to have object selection one needs to be in Object mode, mesh - Edit mode).

Comment: @batFINGER  what do you mean? I was mostly answering the statement in the answer, not sure what should be undone as the answer was reviewed correctly as I understand