# How do I edit a face symmetrically, or copy and mirror it?

Tags: edit-mode, faces, mirror, knife-tool

I want to cut out the shapes seen in the background of the image below, onto the plane:

[image]

I want to do it symmetrically, preferably using the knife tool. The mirror modifier won't work here; I only want symmetry on a specific face, or specific faces, of the object that I'm currently modifying in edit mode. I have already tried using "X mirror" in edit mode options. How can I accomplish a result like this?:

[image]

**Note: I already am using mirror:**

[image]

**If I can't symmetrically use knife,** then I want to do this:
[image]

Comment: This [can be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRrYi.jpg) with Mirror modifier; you just should decide what to model and what to mirror

Comment: @Mr Zak this is nothing more than a face on a mesh, sure you could do it with an entirely different object, but how would I apply this to a specific face on a mesh?

Comment: What does your question mean? There's no difference if it's another object or the same one; from your starting face (which should be split to more faces) extrude faces serving as panels according to the reference, set the origin point and mirror.

Comment: @Mr Zak I am already using a mirror modifier on one side of the object. It would effect the other modifier if I added another. Either way where should I put the origin exactly? On the middle edge of the split face?

Comment: Your situation is not clear. If you mean that the right side on the image shouldn't be affected by the Mirror modifier mirroring geometry on the left side where 2 faces are added then separate objects, mirror as needed; you'll join them later. Origin point should be put where center of the mirror will be.

Comment: @Mr Zak This is what I meant by I already have a mirror: http://i.imgur.com/MgJYy3n.png And is there not an easier/faster way to do this: http://i.imgur.com/5vMEqHt.png

Comment: Why not separate the door into another object and add a mirror modifier there? If need be you can then re-joint it back after you finish modelling

Comment: I'm going to need to do a lot of panels like this. It would take much longer.

Comment: shouldn't "interactive mirror (ctrl-m) be able to handle this? like in http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10598/919